# ParallelTable running on outermost index only

Tags: parallelization

I need to run a simple `ParallelTable`:

```
ParallelTable[
  {tab1[[i1]], tab2[[i2]], tab3[[i3]], tab4[[i4]],
   fun[tab1[[i1]],tab2[[i2]],tab3[[i3]],tab4[[i4]]]
  }, 
  {i1, 1, n1}, {i2, 1, n2}, {i3, 1,n3}, {i4, 1, n4}
]
```

The computation, however, is parallelized only on the outermost index `i1` and not on all of them. The problem is that I have more cores than `n1` and so I'm not computing this table as fast as I had hoped. Is there a simple way to run on as many cores as possible without having to rewrite the table in a flattened version?

Comment: Actually this looks like an excellent candidate for flattening.  Do you really need the higher dimensional array in the output, or will a flat one do as well?  (Sorry, I don't know the answer to your actual question.  But this looks like something I would have flattened before parallelization even if I don't know about this limitation of `ParallelTable`.  You can use `Tuples` to make the parameter list.)

Comment: Do you have a license for all of the cores? A standard installation runs on max 4 cores if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: the `ni` are generally all equal to 2 in the specific case i'm dealing with

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you please give me an example on how to use `Tuples` to run a flattened version of the table? thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't need a high-dimensional tensor as the output (from the code it seems you don't, since you're including all parameters in each output), I recommend you use a flattened table instead.  This will make sure that the available cores can be used optimally.

`Tuples` gives you an easy way to parallelize this calculation.  Assuming that the length of `tab1` is `n1`, etc.,

```
ParallelMap[Append[#, fun @@ #]&, Tuples[{tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4}]]
```

will do what you need.

I typically use this approach (though I like to define `fun` to take a list as one argument instead of a number of arguments).

Comment: Very keen, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One solution that I can see is nesting a `ParallelTable` inside a `Table`.

Original code (I have four cores, so I let the loop index stop at 3 for this demo):

```
ParallelTable[Labeled[Framed[{i, j}], $KernelID], {i, 3}, {j, 6}]// TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Indeed, only 3 cores have been used

```
Table[ParallelTable[Labeled[Framed[{i, j}], $KernelID], {j, 6}], {i, 3}] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now all four are used.